# How to send a "picture in a html page" to a folder in web page

Tags: html

I generate picture in html page... I want to send that picture to the folder of

> `"www.webpage.com/pictures"`

with a  button...

How can I do that?

Comment: How are you generating the image? Uploaded by user? stolen from another website? coded in Javascript? Coded on the server in something else?

Comment: it is generating by an API of another program by javascript..

Comment: data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgo.......

This is generated image link. start like that and verylong

Comment: any help about my question?